# Type 'dao.DBEngine' is not defined, Type 'dao.Recordset' is not defined, and Type 'dao.Workspace' is not defined VB.NET 2008 to 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, project, upgrade

I have a VB.NET project that I have converted from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010. In VS 2008 the project compiles and runs just fine. When I converted it to VS 2010, I get a lot of errors with the DAO objects. This program connects to a SQL database not an Access database. I checked that the DAO reference was added in the project, it was but it says `the system cannot find reference specified`.

Here is a screen shot of my my references:

[image: DOA Ref Pic]

The code and the errors:

```
Module UpgradeSupport
Friend DAODBEngine_definst As New dao.DBEngine
```

> Error: Type 'dao.DBEngine' is not defined

```
Dim r As dao.Recordset
```

> Error: Type 'dao.Recordset' is not defined

```
Dim selProdODBC As dao.Workspace
```

> Error: Type 'dao.Workspace' is not defined

Can someone please tell me what I need to do, in order to make my project work in Visual Studio 2010, like it did in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Do you have a Reference in the project to the correct .dll? [VB 2010 doesn't recognize DAO.DBEngine](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/098b76f9-ce56-4345-bed6-1e2f3283c428/vb-2010-doesnt-recognize-daodbengine?forum=Vsexpressvb)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have updated my question, thank you for asking about that.

Comment: So it looks like you need to add the references to the correct versions of whatever cannot be found, then remove any which cannot be found. Also, your question and title seem to be alternating between VS2010 and VS2012.

Comment: @AndrewMorton No the the project is alternating between 2008 and 2010. I am not sure what the correct reference version of DAO is that should be installed for Visual Studio 2010. I just know that it worked back in 2008.

Comment: Why are you still using DAO in 2014? ADO.Net is the current recommended platform, and has been now for more than 10 years.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn This project is 10 years old. They were still using DAO in 2008 as well as ADO.NET I am trying to convert from VB6 to 2010. I have successfully converted the project from VB6 to 2008, now I would like to get to 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get DAO to work as a reference in Visual Studio 2010, you have add the ACEDAO.DLL to your project. I got the .DLL file from my machine, it was in the office programs files. Once you add the .DLL file, you will have to add the correct import to your project.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access
```