# How to stop form's Load event handler skipping some statements

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB 2017. When I run my project, the form's Load event gets as far as the statement `Dim engdb As New DAO.DBEngine` and then jumps to the end of the Sub. I can't solve it. please help me

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim fullPath As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim engdb As New DAO.DBEngine   '<===== read this line and jump to end sub
    Dim db As DAO.Databas    
    db = engdb.OpenDatabase(fullPath & "filename.accdb", False, False)
    '...
    '.
End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely, that line is throwing an exception; but there's a bug that, when an exception is thrown in the load event of a form, such exception is lost and the code just exits the event. Move your code to the `shown` event of your form to see the error.

Comment: thanks, I put code in form show event, when arrive that line, appearance error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000100-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

Comment: Seems like either Access or your whole Office's installacion is corrupted. Try repairing/reinstalling Office, or checking that all the necesary components of Access are installed. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195380/type-dao-dbengine-is-not-defined-type-dao-recordset-is-not-defined-and-typ) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/786fdf78-d2c9-44e5-b7e7-c8185f6f9107/dao-in-vs2015?forum=vbgeneral) to see if any of that helps

Comment: I was still young the last time I used DAO. I think it was in the last century. Check out some ADO.net code and you will have way less trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Surround code in a try/catch block and you will be able to see why it is erroring/jumping to the end of the sub.
Example:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim fullPath As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
        Dim engdb As New DAO.DBEngine   '<===== read this line and jump to end sub
        Dim db As DAO.Databas    
        db = engdb.OpenDatabase(fullPath & "filename.accdb", False, False)
        '...
        '.

    Catch ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End try

End Sub
```